# How to free C++ instance in JNI?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, jnienv

I want to know how to free the instance of c++ class.
I tried like this but error occurred.

```
Live *pLive = Live::getInstance();
// do something with pLive
env->DeleteLocalRef(reinterpret_cast<jobject>(pLive));
```

I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the definition of `Live`. Especially as it appears to be a singleton...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not calling anything on env to create the object, I assume Live::getInstance returns a C++ object and not a JNI object?  In that case, use delete.  You only use DeleteLocalRef on a JNI object.  (A JNI object is an object that actually exists inside the JVM and is directly accessible in Java).  Trying to DeleteLocalRef on a C++ object will always crash, as its not in the JVM's shared memory

Comment: As it is not a Java object reference, you mean.